# Magento 2 - Mass update of value of custom EAV attribute

Tags: magento2

We've got custom EAV attribute for `product` entity, which needs to be updated regurarly (once a day). We have about 1000 products for now, but amount of products will be growing up quickly.

How to mass update the value of this attribute for all products without killing the web server?

At the moment we are using `$product->setData(...,...)` and `save` product through Product Repository. The server terminates execution after about 250 products though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action as ProductAction;
```

Then

```
public function __construct(
    ProductAction $productAction
) {
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
}
```

Now simply use the following way:

```
$this->productAction->updateAttributes(
    [$product->getId()],
    $attributes,
    $product->getStoreId()
);
```

Here **$attributes** is key => value array